# How to run the Protractor tests in the Travis CI current build

Tags: protractor, travis-ci

I am new to Protractor and Travis CI.
I am writing my tests in Protractor and my CI is Travis, I want to know how I can run the test on the build that is being generated in the travis when there is trigger for travis rather than a dev environment. The dev environment would be updated only after build is succeeded.

So is there a way to point my tests to the build url in travis.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to run Protractor tests against dedicated dev server you can define it explicitly.
There is `baseUrl` property in config object in Protractor config file.

One of the options is to set this variable to another value if there is Travis CI environment.

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/'; // This should be local webserver
if (process.env.TRAVIS) {           
  url = 'http://yourdevelopmentserver' // Change to your dev server
}

exports.config = {
  baseUrl: url
}
```

Reference config file in Protractor repository [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/example/conf.js)

Travis CI has a number of environment variables in docs [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables)